# references for holomorphic principal bundles (over complex manifolds)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, principal-bundles

principal bundles in differential geometry is a classical notion and there are so many references that discuss these notion (even in text books). But, when it comes to its version in complex geometry, namely holomorphic principal bundles over complex manifolds, there does not seem to be much literature.

There are some papers devoted to holomorphic principal bundle when the base has some extra properties (Riemann surfaces, complex projective varieties, and so on), but I am not able to find much literature for a holomorphic principal bundle over an arbitrary complex manifolds.

Are there references that discusses the general notion: holomorphic principal bundles over complex manifolds? If there are any, please provide details.

Comment: holomorphic vector bundles are very popular.. but, holomorphic principal bundles does not seem to be that popular yet... there are only one or two relevant results came when I searched for "holomorphic principal bundles" in google..

Comment: I often recommend Atiyah, Complex analytic connections in fiber bundles, TAMS, 1957. It is not a reference for the general theory, but a very elegant paper in which Atiyah makes important discoveries about holomorphic principal bundles.

Comment: @BenMcKay yes.. i remember seeing (complex analytic) principal bundle over complex manifolds.. i am thinking why is there not much work... I see some ork of Indranil..

Comment: For some results, once the case of vector bundles is handled, the case of principal bundles is easy. For example for the nonabelian Hodge correspondence this is discussed by Carlos Simpson in his paper "Higgs bundles and local systems".

Comment: @WillSawin can you suggest some references where I can see some details about holomorphic principal bundles...

Comment: You could also try to search holomorphic *torsors*?

Comment: @Z.M Not many results are coming for holomorphic torsors... If you have any specific reference in mind, please share..

Comment: I think Kobayashi has a book on this.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you mean https://www.mathsoc.jp/assets/pdf/publications/pubmsj/Vol15.pdf?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Right.

Comment: I think there's a paper of Cartan on this, I'll have to ask the student I know who's looking at it to find out what it is.

Comment: Henri Cartan's paper _Espaces fibres analytiques_ in the proceedings https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/mexico.pdf  is what I was thinking about.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Is there any English reference by any change..

Comment: @MoisheKohan that is only for vector bundles, right? Not for principal bundles..

Comment: I am not sure what "that" refers to, but Kobayashi's book is entirely about holomorphic vector bundles. Principal bundles are hardly mentioned (appear in 10 or so pages).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik sorry, this is the only one that comes to mind

Comment: @MoisheKohan my question was related to principal bundles..so, I mentioned that, Kobayashi reference does not say manythings about principal bundles, so, not really useful for this situation..